# Type hinting additional attribute of a protocol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to type hint an additional attribute of an attribute of a class?

I have a class attribute `Outer.inner` that can be any instance of a class that conforms to a protocol `InnerProto`.

```py
#### I do not control this code #######
from typing import Protocol

class InnerProto(Protocol):
    arg: int

class OuterProto(Protocol):
    inner: InnerProto
```

`Inner` class conforms to the protocol `InnerProto`, but it also has an additional attribute (which as far as I understand doesn't violate protocol conformity)

```py
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, inner: InnerProto):
        self.inner: InnerProto = inner

class Inner:
    def __init__(self, arg: int):
        self.arg: int = arg  # this is part of the protocol
        self.arg2: int = arg  # this is not
```

Pycharm (v2021.2) inspection highlights the attribute `arg2` as an unresolved attribute.

```py
def test_type_hint_example():
    obj = Outer(Inner(1))
    assert obj.inner.arg == 1
    assert obj.inner.arg2 == 1 # inspection highlights arg2 as "unresolved attribute"
```

[image]

Is it possible to typehint so that inspection recognizes what arg2 is?

Normally I would be inclined to alter the type hint of `Outer.inner` but in this case that would be a mistake.  `inner` can be ANY class that conforms to `InnerProto`.

My second thought was to override the type-hint for the attribute of the instance.  This type of trick has worked non-attribute objects, but in this case it results in a different inspection error: "Non-self attribute could not be type hinted"

```py
def test_option1():
    obj = Outer(Inner(1))
    obj.inner: Inner   # fixes inspection for arg2, but "Non-self attribute could not be type hinted" occurs
    assert obj.inner.arg == 1
    assert obj.inner.arg2 == 1
```

[image]

What other options are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the code isn't type-safe.

Your `Outer.__init__` function is:

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, inner: InnerProto):
        self.inner = inner

    # <-- snip -->
```

You've annotated the `inner` argument with `InnerProto`. That means that the `Outer.inner` attribute could be of *any* type, as long as that type conforms to the `InnerProto` protocol.

According to you, this is the correct type-hint:

> Normally I would be inclined to alter the type hint of `Outer.inner` but in this case that would be a mistake.  `inner` can be ANY class that conforms to `InnerProto`.

If this is the case, then there is no way for a static type-checker to verify that `Outer.inner` will have any attributes or methods that are not specified in `InnerProto`. This is why the type-checker is raising an error in your `test_type_hint_example` function: you've told the type-checker that `Outer.inner` could be of any type as long as that type conforms to `InnerProto`, but `InnerProto` says nothing about an `arg2` attribute, and not all python types have an `arg2` attribute, so therefore there's a possibility that you'll get an `AttribiteError` when you access `Outer.inner.arg2`.

If you are *certain* that, in the context of this *specific* function, `Outer.inner` will be of type `Inner`, and therefore can be guaranteed to have an `arg2` attribute  — despite the fact that in most situations, `Outer.inner` "could be ANY class that conforms to `InnerProto`" — then you could use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) like this:

```
from typing import cast

def test_type_hint():
    obj = Outer(Inner(1))
    inner = cast(Inner, obj.inner)
    assert inner.arg == 1
    assert inner.arg2 == 1
```

In reality, however, if you *are* certain that `Outer.inner` can be guaranteed to have an `arg2` attribute, that most likely indicates that you do, in fact, have the wrong type hint for `Outer.inner` (it's hard to tell you what the right type hint is without seeing more of your code base). Using `typing.cast` in the way I've just demonstrated above should generally only be used as a last resort — it's more a method of evading the type-checker, which won't help you in the long run if your code isn't type-safe.

Comment: yoru ratiobnale is ok, but the test, as you put it, does not make much sense: it is testing an explicit cast that is in the test code itself. In a case like this, if `Inner.arg2` is ever expected to be used in `Outer` code, it should be annotated like so - either `Outer` should require an specific `Inner` object, or another protocol should be declared, annotating `arg2` as well.

Comment: @jsbueno I completely agree. I am sceptical of OP's claim that it "would be a mistake" to change the type hint to something more specific, hence why I said that I believed the code fundamentally wasn't type-safe. Using `cast` in this situation would be evading the type checker rather than heeding its warning. Perhaps I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: @jsbueno the "test" function was copied from the original question — it was at that point that MyPy flagged an error in the original code. I agree it doesn't make much sense to use `asserts` like that immediately after an explicit cast; it was more to show that MyPy would no longer raise the error at that specific point if you had used `typing.cast` in that way.

Comment: The real world code my example comes from has the `Outer` type hints existing in a library not controlled by me.  The `Inner` I pass in conforms to the protocol but it of course has other arguments.  @AlexWaygood I think your suggestion to use a cast is the best option here.